# Angular Observable: Unable to read property Length inside Subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I've recently started developing using Angular, and I'm still in learning mode. So, I have this dilemma, which I need to access the "Length" property of an array inside of .Subscribe of an Observable; which I'm currently getting undefined. Strange, because I can see the Array values, but when calling Length I get undefined.

This is my code...

```js
category: Observable<Category>;
categorySubject = new Subject<Category>();
categorySubscription: Subscription;


  
constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

retreivingItems() {
this.fetchCategoryItems("").subscribe((items) => {
  console.log(items.properties); // Properties are available
  console.log('properties[] length = ' + items.properties.length); // output is still undefined
})


}


fetchCategoryItems(category: string) {
  // Get data from firebase    
  return this.db
  .collection('category')
  .doc(category)
  .get()
  .pipe(      
    map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data() as Category
    }))     
  );
}

}

// Category & Property Model
export interface Category {
    category_name: string,
    properties: Array<Property>
}

export interface Property {
    field_name: string,
    field_tpye: string
}
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhohs.png)

I have also tries using a Subject to wrap the Observable, but I still get undefined.

My guess is that on the Subscribe, the category values hasn't still finished gathering all the streamed data... so how can I achieve this?

Output: [undefined_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYjE6.png)

Comment: From what you describe I believe properties is not an array even if you say so. Could you double check? Share the console output please.

Comment: export interface Category {
    category_name: string,
    properties: Array<Property>
}

export interface Property {
    field_name: string,
    field_tpye: string
}`

Comment: {properties: Array(4)}
properties
: 
Array(4)
0
: 
{type: 'string', name: 'manufacturer'}
1
: 
{name: 'model_number', type: 'string'}
2
: 
{type: 'string', name: 'serial_number'}
3
: 
{name: 'maintenance_date', type: 'string'}
length
: 
4
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

Comment: The first output is an object containing another properties field, which is the array.  Try console.log(items.properties.properties.length);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A few things to clear out first:

1. "Observables" emit data when you "subscribe" to it. When you call `db.collection().doc().get()`, you basically "prepare" the observable to emit data.
2. Observables which get "completed" at any point in future (i.e. network calls), those are completed immediately. So you don't need to "unsubscribe" those observables.

Now, in your code, you have defined `fetchCategoryItems` to store the observable in the `category` property, which looks unnecessary. Since you are calling the [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) database, it's a network call and is immediately completed upon successful response. So, you can modify this class in question (assuming it's a [service provider](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services)) like the following:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CategoryService {
  constructor(private readonly db: AngularFirestore) {}
  fetchItems(category: string) {
    return this.db.collection('category').doc(category).get().pipe(map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })));
  }
}
```

Notice how we have set it up to return an observable from `fetchItems` method. All is left now is to subscribe to this observable and get the data. In the component file, you can do:

```js
@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class CategoryComponent {
  constructor(private readonly categoryService: CategoryService) {}
  onFetch() {
    this.categoryService.fetchItems().subscribe((items) => {
      console.log(items.properties); // not `undefined`
      console.log(items.properties.length); // it should be `4` according to your question
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now it makes more sense. But after implementing changes as suggested, I still get undefined when trying get length out of properties Array... I will place a screenshot of the result on the description, so you can take a look.

Comment: I had posted an image of the output in de above description as "undefined_output"

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) / [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) using [a dummy API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com)?